# Are non-rigorous questions allowed on MSE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

By non-rigorous questions I mean questions not of the form "Prove that ...".

For instance:

"Is there a clever way to check this type of *equality*?"

"Does this *math thing* remind you of anything?"

"Is there a way to do *math thing* using *math thing*?"

"Do these *math things* relate?"

Essentially kinda of vague meta-questions about math.

Comment: All of those questions look off-topic to me.  The problem is not the lack of rigour, but the lack of *focus*.  Good questions for the SE format are narrowly focused, and permit objective, authoritative answers.  Most of those questions look pretty broad, and seem to invite discussion more than answers.

Comment: There is a [soft-question tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question)

Comment: Do you have such questions in mind?

Comment: Some questions asking for clever ways: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362907/clever-way-to-simplify-sum and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005411/clever-way-to-find-cosets and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699138/clever-way-to-square-a-matrix and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777308/how-to-combine-unitary-matrices-in-a-clever-way and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576436/clever-way-to-determine-area-of-irregular-shape and many others.

Comment: math thing using math thing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502834/how-to-solve-this-using-using-stirling-approx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142499/are-sets-constructed-using-only-zf-measurable-using-zfc and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234972/using-r-versus-using-r-for-double-integration and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708300/volume-using-shells and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855649/using-substitution-while-using-taylor-expansion and many more.

Comment: If the questions are just one liners as in OP they lack context and should be closed. On the other hand, without non rigorous brainstorming there is less innovation. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805945/cartans-magic-formula-and-geometric-product) is imho an acceptable "non rigorous" question of that kind.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Something worth noting about those examples is that most of them are about a decade old.  The most recent is from 2019 ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/768625/)), and that question seems to be fairly well fleshed out and specified.  I also think that questions of the form "Can [X] be used to do [Y]?" are more likely to be on-topic than the other prompts, which are *super* vague.

Comment: @Xander, plenty of recent questions asking for clever ways. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845573/solving-for-the-third-angle-by-taking-the-cos-of-two-arccoss-added-together and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4843830/how-to-solve-2d-poisson-equation-for-coordinate-independent-source and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840890/primitive-of-e-frac-11-x2 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839286/matrix-operations-that-preserve-sum-of-elements just from the last week or two.

Comment: Those [question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615) suck.